# Write custom xml message to database

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net AdoNetAppender with C# to log a custom XML message into a database. I have a stored procedure that takes one parameter as a XML format.
Here is a part of my config file:

```xml
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <threshold value="ALL" />
    <reconnectOnError value="true" />
    <param name="ConnectionType" value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxdfasdfas" />
    <param name="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=myserver;integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=mydatabase; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=me;Password=me;" />
    <param name="UseTransactions" value="False" />
    <commandText value="dbo.InsertLog " />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@LogEntries" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{LogEntries}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

With log4net, I should be able to do something like this,

```cs
mylogger.Info(FormatToXML(ID,Date,LogLevel,message)); //FormatToXML takes these arguments, and create XMLElement
```

However, above line doesn't insert anything to the database. I have log4net debugger turned on, but I didn't see any errors/exception.

But, this works,

```cs
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogEntries"] = FormatToXML(ID,Date,LogLevel,message);
mylogger.Info("");
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong where I should be able to just call `mylogger.Info(...)`.

Can anybody see where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using custom property to get the value in the parameter in layout. Change the layout pattern by simply using the `%message`.

```xml
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@LogEntries" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

Now will work normally with `mylogger.Info(...)`.